# Emberjs create a table with CollectionView

Tags: ember.js

I wanted to generate a table with an array that I have in a controller but I don't really understand how does the collectionView is working.

Here are my array :

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    accountProfile: null, //

    actions: {
        [...] //Action that initialize the accountProfile (object)
    } 
})
```

My array is accessible like this => view.accountProfile.dialInNumbers when I want to display on a template.

So now I have a table, but it must respect some standards like that :

```
<table class="table-history">
    <tr>
        <td class="col-left">+44734567890</td>
        <td>
            <div class="ph-img"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="tr-img"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Most likely what you have in the `<tr>` tag is what must be generated by the view. Most likely I will always have the first `<td>` that will change from the array in the view. The others `<td>` are meant to be the same every row.

My problem is that I don't really know how I can manage to create the collectionView and add the different class name with the others `<td>` in the same row..

I have seen some people doing this : 
`myView.appendTo('.table-history');`

or even like this :

```
{#collection App.myView}}
<td>{{content}}</td>
{{/collection}}
```

But I'm kinda lost in this..

[EDIT]

I manage to make it works like this :

```
App.CallBackListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: 'tbody',
    content: ['A','B','C']
})

{{#collection App.CallBackListView}}
    <td class="col-left">{{content}}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="ph-img"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="tr-img"></div>
    </td>
{{/collection}}
```

But I have one problem here, is that there is display in {{content}}. I don't really understand this..

Comment: Why are you using a CollectionView instead of just a route and controller?  How are you loading the data?

Comment: I am using the view because I save my data from the localstorage or in my object. I have created a method to store my data and retrieve them directly by using this : Services.Storages.getString() etc..

I am using the view because I need them to be refresh, and also need to interact with the collection. Like remove or add item in the table.

Comment: Have you looked into use Ember-Data with the localStorage adapter to handle this?  It may be a better solution.  You should be able to accomplish the rest using a traditional model-view-controller paradigm.  Are you dead set on using a CollectionView?

Comment: I would rather not using ember-Data, because I'm using a a backend developped by someone else already and I have to adapt it with emberjs. And the way how they developped it, that make me more useful to use the collectionview rather than the model hook. But I have found my problem in here. It was coming from the `{{content}}` I just needed to call them like that instead `{{view.content}}` I feel so stupid..